# Calculating the difference between two times using php, and then adding it to a total of time type

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

Hi I have a problem where I am trying to get a total time that a job has taken (using database fields job_start and job_end time(7))
then adding this to another model's field,

the code i have is

```
 if (isset($_POST['Jobs'])) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Jobs'];
        $model->setScenario('closejob');
        $model->status = 2; //set status to closed

        //date time difference - this is the part I need help with 
        $diff = $model->job_start - $model->job_end;
        //need to get customer model and add time diff to it 
        $customermodel = Customers::model()->findByPk($model->customer_ID);
        $customermodel->total_time = $customermodel->total_time + $diff;
        $customermodel->save();



        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->job_ID));
    }
```

I have tried string to time and other date functions but to no avail , the above code throws the following error

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string..

Any ideas on the proper way to do this ?
i.e am I going about the adding of time and calculating the differences all wrong ?

I think it has something to do with converting the string to a time format but  I am unsure how to do this

Comment: exactly how are you storing those date/time values? "character string" suggests you're using a varchar, or trying to pass around invalid date string formats.

Comment: @MarcB they are all stored in the database as time(7)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to do

```
$diff = $model->job_end - $model->job_start;
```

Instead of

```
$diff = $model->job_start - $model->job_end;
```

Comment: yes you are correct about that part, thanks . I don't think that's the issue as I have Updated it and I am still getting the error

Comment: Have you the `$diff` result? Is it a string, int, float?

Comment: I am struggling to dump vars in yii , nothing seems to work, i'd use xdebug but it doesnt work in iis, I know that when the times are displayed in the app they are in the following format '14:00:00.0000000' if  thats any help

Comment: If you have something like log4php, you could first log your model var like `$logger->debug(print_r($model, true));`, and see what are the values of `job_start` and `job_end`. Then, do the same with `$diff`. Maybe `$diff` is an empty string (''), so your addition can not work...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an attached behavior for that model, it is likely that your job_start and job_end attributes are strings that are formatted according to MSSQL, assuming the column types are a date/time representation. This is certainly the way `CActiveRecord` models work with MySQL and Yii with DATETIME type.

To do differences, you would need to convert first. Take a look at `CDateFormatter` and use it to convert your attributes to numerical representations that allow for arithmetic.

If you cannot get Xdebug to work, then invest time in getting the Yii::log() function working (it will output to `runtime/application.log` by default.